# Copy one access database into another database with C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, jet

Is it possible to copy programmatically all the tables in one database into another database that might already contain tables (and if there is any repeated name throw an exception of course)? This implies creating the tables in the destination database with the proper structures and with the same name as on the source database.

I found a few similar questions but none of them have this particular need.

I'm using the Jet engine.

Comment: I know it isn't programming, but access (2010 at least) has a "Move Data" option under database tools, which will move to SQL Server or another Access Database, maybe you can utilise that though a Macro?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
string query = "SELECT * INTO [dest_table] FROM [source_table] IN '" + sourceDataBaseFileName + "'";
using (OleDbCommand sqlCeCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, DbConnection))
{
    sqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Do this for every table in the source. `source_table` and `dest_table` can be the same name. The `DbConnection` is the destination database.

Comment: This does nothing to resolve the issue of pre-existing tables with the same names. It also creates tables that lack indexes and don't necessarily have the correct data types.

Comment: why wouldnt they have the correct data type? doesn't that create an exact copy of the table?

Comment: You are right primary keys become normal columns. But they don't become another data type.

Comment: No, it doesn't create an exactly copy of the table. Data types may or may not be correct (I was thinking of MakeTables with queries that might have expression-based columns in the SELECT statement; e.g., if a column evaluates to Null, you'll get a binary field). In addition to the lack of indexes (it's not just the PKs that don't get created, but all indexes), you also don't have any of the validation rules (field-level or table-level), nor any of the foreign-key constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question. Perhaps this answer will help someone else.

Manipulating the COM interface of Microsoft Access seems to provide most of what you are looking for.

- Add a reference to the "Microsoft Access xx.x Object Library"
- Create and instantiate a object of type "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application"
- Call OpenCurrentDatabase with a parm for your source database
- Call DoCmd.CopyObject with the parms for your target database, the name of the target table, object type (AcObjectType.acTable), and the name of your source table
- Call CloseCurrentDatabase

In VB.Net, it's something like this:

```
acdb = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application
acdb.OpenCurrentDatabase("source db")
acdb.DoCmd.CopyObject("target db", "target table name", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcObjectType.acTable, "source table name")
acdb.CloseCurrentDatabase()
```

I verified the tables are copied correctly, with proper column types and indexes and keys.  However, it seems to overwrite the target table if it already exists without any warnings or exceptions.

See this MSDN [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff844724.aspx) for details.

When I researching how to do this, I misunderstood what I read, as I thought this was DAO.  It's been a very long time since I've used DAO, so I didn't realize the errors in my ways.  Thank you Gord Thompson for setting me straight.

This does require MSACCESS being installed on the machine this is running on.  The more complicated approach would be to use ADOX, which also has its own drawbacks IMHO.

This is with Office 2010.  Obviously YMMV with other versions.

If only some day Microsoft started using .Net for Office as they tell the rest of the world to do.

Comment: *"I read somewhere else that DAO requires that Access be on the PC this is running on."* - No. Access DAO is part of the Access Database Engine, not part of the Microsoft Access (GUI) application itself. The older 32-bit "Jet" DAO (for .mdb files only) is included with Windows. The newer "ACE" DAO (for both .mdb and .accdb files) is available as a free download of the Access Database Engine redistributable in both 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

Comment: Having said that, your proposed solution *does* require that the full Access application be installed because it does *not* use DAO; it uses COM automation of the Microsoft Access application (MSACCESS.EXE) itself. The required reference for an `Access.Application` object is "Microsoft Access XX.X Object Library", not "Microsoft Office XX.X Access Database Engine Object Library".

Comment: Thank you.  I got my references mixed up in my solution.  It doesn't help that Visual Studio shows it as "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access" after it's added.